# Closure arguments referenced by position inside nested closure in swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have this piece of code which works fine:

```
var discoverEvents = events.map { event in
   userEvents.find { $0.eventID == event.eventID } ?? event
}
```

I wonder if there is any way to reference `event` by position inside `find` somehow like that:

```
var discoverEvents = events.map { userEvents.find { $$0.eventID == $0.eventID } ?? $0 }
```

to make it one-liner?

Comment: Personally, I'd hope not, at the point that you have nested closures, you're better off being explicit and naming things.  The $positional syntax is really intended for short and quick things like `.map { $0.name }` where you can easily take the whole thing in at a glance.

Comment: @DavidBerry I totally agree, I'm just curious if that is possible at all :)

Answer (score 14):

No, it's not possible. The inner `$0` shadows the outer one, and there is no other way to refer to the `$0` in the outer scope.

As @DavidBerry mentions, that syntax is intended for *short* anonymous functions. Things could get very confusing otherwise.